# How do I center a message in a div via jQuery

Tags: jquery

This is a slideshow, and when you click the questionmark ,more info shows up. The position of the LI is changing over time and is never static.

I'm trying to have a message show up onclick that is hidden. The showing up is easy. However, I want it's left position to be relative to the parent UL not the object's parent which is position relative. Any ideas on how to come up with the math?

I've been struggling with the left position. Suggestions welcome.

Here's my JS (at least how I think it should work:

```
    $('.info_toggle a').click(function() {
    $('.tooltip').hide();
    var left_position = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().position() -1;
    console.log(left_offset);
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().next('.tooltip').show().css('left', 'left_position');
    return false;
});
```

Here: my markup:

```
<ul id="activities_nav" class="clearfix">
<div class="activity_group">

        <li>
            <div class="summary">
                <h4>Category One&nbsp;<span class="info_toggle">(<a href="#">?</a>)</span></h4>
                <p class="num_activities">3</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tooltip" style="display: block; ">
                <a href="#" class="close">close</a>
                <h4>Category Description</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum urna turpis, gravida eu tincidunt a, consequat a mauris. Suspendisse dolor lacus,</p>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li>
            <div class="summary">
                <h4>Category One&nbsp;<span class="info_toggle">(<a href="#">?</a>)</span></h4>
                <p class="num_activities">3</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tooltip" style="display: block; ">
                <a href="#" class="close">close</a>
                <h4>Category Description</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum urna turpis, gravida eu tincidunt a, consequat a mauris. Suspendisse dolor lacus,</p>
            </div>
        </li>
</div>
```

Comment: WHoops, that would be the point of Stackoverflow wouldn't it! Answers accepted where I could.

Answer (score 0):

[Using css](http://www.ehow.com/how_2284643_left-right-center-align-css.html), giving margin-left:auto and margin-right:auto

And then, accepting answers to any of your 7 questions posted at this time. That should do

Comment: Indeed.
Check at this. Works on "position:absolute" styled divs.
http://snipt.org/wommo

Should check if it works in IE, though.

Comment: No, that's not it either. Because the div is rendered relative to it's parent. I need to do the positioning relative to the parent's parent.